# Communicating between fragments xamarin

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using Xamarin for android.
I'm using a FragmentActivity ActionBarSherlock to have 4 tabs that each load a fragment.

One of those tabs hold a ListFragment (A) that holds an adapter that holds a list which is displayed in the Fragment, and another tab holds a simple Fragment (B) which is supposed to add an item to A's list.

How can I access A's list from fragment B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the list in your main activity (FragmentActivity) as public member or create its getter/setter. Now you can access this list in ListFragment (A) and in simple Fragment (B). This access in ListFragment and in simple Fragment can be done by:

```
var myList = ((FragmentActivity)this.Activity).getList();
```

So, the list is now accessible by all fragments inside your Main FragmentActivity.